# Image retrieval API with token and security

Tags: image, api, base64, dynamic-url

I have a bunch of real time IP camera images on the web server.

Is there a way to develop an API (RESTFUL) with token to let developers access those images and still prevent unauthorized user to access those image url?

such as

```
http://example.com/camera1?token=1234&cameraID=camera1
```

If the API returns an URL of

```
http://example.com/camera1.png
```

then everyone can access the `camera1` image without token if he already knows the `camera1` image URL.

It seems I have to use an dynamic URL

```
http://example.com/adfaofnhafa.png
```

instead of fixed name URL to prevent this from happening.

Or I can use image BASE64 encode to conver the image to binary string and return the long string in JSON format.

What's the best way to do this? Each of my image size is under 200KB and I have 150 IP cameras images update in real time and saved on the server hard disk with the fixed name.

How did facebook or youtube do it? If I have already know your facebook photo URL when call the API for the 1st time, after that I can access it anytime and anywhere without call the API again.